# ArrayList to string с пробелами

Tags: c#

Как сделать что бы после каждого слова был пробел но не после последнего?
и еще пользуясь случаям хочу спросить касательно строк

```
char[] word = item.ToCharArray();
string s = new string(word);
```

почему нельзя написать например `string s = word.ToString();`

```
public static class Kata
{
  public static string ReverseWords(string str)
  {
            string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();


            foreach (var item in words)
            {
                char[] word = item.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(word);
                string s = new string(word);
                arr.Add(s);
            }
            string ss = "";
            foreach(var item in arr)
            {
            ss += item + " ";
            }
            return ss;
  }
}
```

Comment: [String.Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: не получается с arraylist

Comment: Так не работает? `String.Join(" ", arr.ToArray())`

Comment: @Kioshilol Если получили ответ, не забудьте позначить его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
string[] sarr = (string[])arr.ToArray(typeof(string));
string res = String.Join(" ", sarr);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

В принципе можно так:

```
var arr = new ArrayList();
string.Join(" ", arr.Cast<string>());
```

Но гораздо лучше отказаться от устаревших коллекций и сделать:

```
var arr = new List<string>();
string.Join(" ", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Уже сам сделал

```
public static class Kata
{
  public static string ReverseWords(string str)
  {
            string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            //not arraylist
            var arr = new List<string>();


            foreach (var item in words)
            {
                char[] word = item.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(word);
                //not string s = word.Tostring();idk why
                string s = new string(word);
                arr.Add(s);
            }
            // string.Join very usefull
            string ss = string.Join<string>(" ", arr);
            return ss;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit a met";
        string[] words = str.Split(new char[]{' '});
        string[] revWords = words.Select(x => string.Join("", x.ToCharArray().Reverse())).ToArray();
        string reversedString = string.Join(" ", revWords);
        Console.WriteLine(reversedString);
        // "merol muspi rolod tis a tem"
    }
}
```

"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xVrixW).